# How to find cause of jQuery incompatibility in apps

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, telerik

I was just given an old app to fix, I was told it doesn't work in IE11 compatibility mode.  I played with it and found it has UI issues in IE7 (datepick calendar dissapears, dropdowns become inactive, etc).  I have been swapping out jquery, jquery UI versions, but that just introduces new bugs, then I had a thought, "There has to be a proven procedure for this."  So I am wondering if anyone has a good approach for debugging UI compatibility issues between IE and jQuery.  Thanks.

This app is using jquery 1.5.1, jquery-ui 1.8.11, and telerik 2011.3.1115. Thius is an ASP MVC3 app, shouldn't there be an ajax script?

Comment: The first thing you should do is make sure you aren't running in quirks mode. If in quirks mode, there isn't a whole lot you can do since jQuery UI assumes you are in standards.

Comment: Hi Kevin. The DTD is  <!DOCTYPE html>.  In IE7, that should be standard rendering, right?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: Can you remove IE11 from the picture and test in IE7 directly? you can fix the IE11 issue with a meta tag pretty easily.

Comment: I fired up my xp mode and checked it there in IE 7 and it is showing the same issue.  I dug a little further, and seems the main issue is with the datepicker.  The version used is separate from the jquery UI file, it is called jquery.datepick.js and jquery.datepick.ext.js.  The datepicker does not render in IE7.  I will switch it to the regular jquery UI datepicker if I have to, but there is a bunch of custom setup being used.

Comment: Open the js file, at the top you should see a url to the plugin itself. Can you share that? It might just be a minor bug that needs an IE7 fix.

Comment: But, to answer your question in general, No, there is no convenient way of finding incompatibility problems other than through testing. Debugging an Ie7 problem is even more difficult due to the poor debugging tools that it comes shipped with.

Comment: Understand on the testing.  I am making some progress, so i will keep at it.  Here is the datepick URL:  http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

Comment: What version of it are you using? For your version of jQuery UI, you should at least be working with 4.0.6

Comment: Yes, that is the version it is using, same with the extensions file.